# How do I allow extension part of e-mail in postfix when doing virtual delivery

Tags: postfix

Currently I have a `/etc/postfix/virtual` file that has entries like:

```
user@foo.com foo@bar.com
```

I want to be able to forward `user+asdf@foo.com` to `foo+asd@bar.com`

How do I do this?

**EDIT:**
I did set

```
propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual
```

and

```
recipient_delimeter = +
```

but still keep getting  `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table;`

**EDIT II**: 
I made the changes suggested in @Schot's updated answer with some progress;

Now I get `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table;` when sending to **user+asdf@foo.com**

Sending to **user@foo.com** worked both before and after them modifications

**EDIT III**:

Postfix is version **2.3.3** - I do not have separate `mail.warn` or `mail.err` logs - just the `/var/log/maillog`. Here is the full (anonymized) snippet:

**EDIT IV**:
Updated to postfix **2.3.19** with no luck.

**EDIT V**:
Doing `postconf -n` showed that `recipient_delimiter` was misspelled in the `main.cf` *as well as above* and the delimiter was not processed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `recipient_delimiter` not `recipient_delimEter`

Answer (score 3):

Your current entries are OK, you should look at the [propagate_unmatched_extensions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#propagate_unmatched_extensions) configuration parameter. Check that it includes `virtual`.

About you regex not working, see the man page for [virtual(8)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html):

> The virtual(8) delivery agent disallows regular expression
>     substitution of  $1  etc.  in  regular  expression  lookup
>     tables, because that would open a security hole.

#### Update

I have tested your configuration and it works for me. Maybe one of the following is the problem:

- Is the virtual domain ("foo.com") listed in `mydestination`? If it is, **remove** it.
- Is the virtual domain listed in `virtual_alias_domains`? If not, add it.

Side note: Does sending mail to user@foo.com (without a +delimiter) work?

Comment: I made the changes, some progress: now I get `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table;` when sending to `user+asdf@foo.com` - `user@foo.com` worked both before and after them modifications

Comment: @Kimvais: I'm running out of ideas... What is your postfix version? Anything in `/var/log/mail.warn` or `/var/log/mail.err`?

Comment: @schot - so am I. Updated the question nevertheless...

Comment: @Kimvais: Version 2.3.3 is pretty old, try upgrading to 2.3.19 or the latest 2.6 or 2.7 release.

Comment: @schot: just upgraded to 2.3.19 - no help. Will try 2.7 next...

Comment: SUCCESS! Finally noticed that there was a typo in my `main.cf` it is `recipient_delimiter` not recipient_delim__e__ter ...

Answer (score 1):

$number substitutions are not allowed in the virtual file as a security precaution. http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html